# I need to connect a HP 230W Docking Station MFG #A7E34AA#ABA to a 2009-2010 27” iMac that has the Mini DisplayPort

Tags: macos, imac

I need to connect a HP 230W Docking Station MFG #A7E34AA#ABA to a 2009-2010 27” iMac that has the Mini DisplayPort.
The apple iMAC specs say that the Mini DisplayPort offers input so that I can connect any external source that has DisplayPort output. 
I have a Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter attached to the iMac via the Mini DisplayPort then a standard VGA cable running from the docking station to the VGA Adapter. 
I don’t see anything on the iMAC.  Is there some configuration setting to change making this port input and not output, am I just doing something wrong or can this setup not be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

[Apple states](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924#3) that you must use a Mini DisplayPort or a Thunderbolt port on the source computer. That implies that using a VGA adapter will not work, but it might.

Are you using Target Display Mode? You need to press Command-F2 on the iMac.